# How to get the correct inferred type when passing a return-value as a closure variable which captured by its own function body?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typing

TS version: 3.7

code as below, and notice its comment, how can I use the `self.fourtyTwo` safely.

```
type RefSelf<Input extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => unknown>> = {
  [k in keyof Input]: () => ReturnType<Input[k]>
}

declare function calculate <
  Input extends Record<string, (self: RefSelf<Input>) => unknown>,
>(input: Input): RefSelf<Input>

const { fourtyTwo, fourtyTwo2 } = calculate({
  fourtyTwo: () => 42,
  // (parameter) self: RefSelf<{fourtyTwo: unknown; fourtyTwo2: unknown;}>
  // (property) fourtyTwo: () => any
  fourtyTwo2: (self) => self.fourtyTwo(),
})
```

playground: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShBmBlCAbeAeAkgOzAV2CggA9gJsATAZ1ggGMB7AJwvSuCYEtsBzAGigAKAHSiAhkx5UAXFDHYQAbQC6ASigBeAHxQ82ANbYGAd2xadGqAG8AUFCiL9UblH0QQDeFBz5gy2YLq2rTAeEzYACrgEFi4BI7KWjYAvjY2FPQoEtDwenTAnAzYUHRiKHR4WWRQ6HbecYQkZJQ0cIwsbBzc-EJUqPCycEj9sb5aQTp6hiZmfDZagty+sj4EqoMIyGijBEk2jNjs1lDwDGGgEcYMAqfnIJcMAExQyZolZRVVEIK29rdMFyuAQmUAALI85vYAPRQoRgCRiAC2EDITHUfTQG2G2ys-0BDFkUyMpgA3CczgD7ldHoSDMTsCTkklobDBGAmAxIJT1HiqQShCD5CA6ryHjTev0QRj4MJRVdAnNkqogA

Comment: Wow, I don't know how to do this with type inference or if it's even possible; seems like it would require multiple rounds of inference for a single object, and the compiler gives up.

Comment: What about a [builder](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.6.3#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) instead?

Comment: See [relevant GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34865#issuecomment-548867473) about why this won't work.  I'd be happy to write this explanation up as an answer with the builder as a possible solution, if it addresses your question.

Comment: @jcalz It seems like a halting problem, type inference tries to get types eagerly.